# when i am using 3 view on viewcontroller it get slow in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am using 3 view on one UIViewController. Because of this I have lots of code in viewDidLoad() Like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    customActivityIndicator.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-0.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-1.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-2.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-3.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-4.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-5.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-6.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-7.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-8.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-9.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-10.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-11.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-12.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-13.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-14.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-15.gif"],nil];
    customActivityIndicator.animationDuration = 1.0; // in seconds
    customActivityIndicator.animationRepeatCount = 0; // sets to loop

    [customActivityIndicator startAnimating];

    btn.hidden=YES;


    UILabel *lab =[[UILabel alloc] init];
    lab.text =  [NSString awesomeIcon:FaMailReply];

    UIImage *listImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backicon.png.png"];
    UIButton *listButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    listButton2.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [[listButton2 layer] setBorderWidth:0.5f];
    listButton2.layer.borderColor =[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    listButton2.layer.cornerRadius = btn.bounds.size.width / 3.4;// this value vary as per your desire
    listButton2.clipsToBounds = YES;

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:15.0];
    UIColor *color = [UIColor blueColor];

    NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font,NSFontAttributeName,color,NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
    //  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font,NSFontAttributeName,color,NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

    NSAttributedString *attributedStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lab.text attributes:attrsDictionary];



    // get the image size and apply it to the button frame
    CGRect listButton2Frame = listButton2.frame;
    listButton2Frame.size = listImage2.size;
    listButton2.frame = listButton2Frame;

    [listButton2 setAttributedTitle:attributedStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [listButton2 addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(LogoutClick:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *jobsButton2 =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:listButton2];


    //Notificaation Icon Button...


    UILabel *lablnotification =[[UILabel alloc] init];
    //    lab.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:8];
    //  lab.textColor =  [UIColor whiteColor];
    lablnotification.text =  [NSString awesomeIcon:FaHome];

    UIImage *listImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notification.png"];
    UIButton *listButton4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    listButton4.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [[listButton4 layer] setBorderWidth:0.5f];
    listButton4.layer.borderColor =[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    listButton4.layer.cornerRadius = btn.bounds.size.width / 3.4;// this value vary as per your desire
    listButton4.clipsToBounds = YES;

    UIFont *fontnotification = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:18.0];
    UIColor *colornotification = [UIColor blueColor];

    NSDictionary *attrsDictionarynotification = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fontnotification,NSFontAttributeName,colornotification,NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
    //  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font,NSFontAttributeName,color,NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

    NSAttributedString *attributedStrnotification = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lablnotification.text attributes:attrsDictionarynotification];

    // get the image size and apply it to the button frame
    CGRect listButton4Frame = listButton4.frame;
    listButton4Frame.size = listImage4.size;
    listButton4.frame = listButton4Frame;

    [listButton4 setAttributedTitle:attributedStrnotification forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [listButton4 addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(ActualNotificationClick:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *jobsButton4 =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:listButton4];

    UIImage *listImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ec2.png"];
    UIButton *listButton3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    // get the image size and apply it to the button frame
    CGRect listButton3Frame = listButton3.frame;
    listButton3Frame.size = listImage3.size;
    listButton3.frame = listButton3Frame;

    [listButton3 setImage:listImage3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [listButton3 addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(EmployeeClick:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *jobsButton3 =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:listButton3];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:jobsButton2,jobsButton4, nil];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:jobsButton3, nil];


    //NSUserDefault...

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    userid = [defaults objectForKey:@"UserId"];
    NSLog(@"User Id is =%@",userid);
    ServerString=[defaults objectForKey:@"ServerString"];

    DefaultRegionIDString=[defaults objectForKey:@"DefaultRegionIDString"];
    DefaultBranchIDString=[defaults objectForKey:@"DefaultBranchIDString"];
    DefaultSiteIDString=[defaults objectForKey:@"DefaultSiteIDString"];
    DefaultLocationString=[defaults objectForKey:@"DefaultLocationString"];
    DefaultDateString =[defaults objectForKey:@"DefaultDateString"];
    DefaultTimeString =[defaults objectForKey:@"DefaultTimeString"];
    DefaultEmployeeNameString=[defaults objectForKey:@"DefaultEmployeeNameString"];
    DefaultRegionNameString=[defaults objectForKey:@"DefaultRegionNameString"];
    DefaultBranchNameString=[defaults objectForKey:@"DefaultBranchNameString"];
    DefaultSiteNameString=[defaults objectForKey:@"DefaultSiteNameString"];
    DefaultEventTypeString=[defaults objectForKey:@"DefaultEventTypeString"];
    DefaultIncidentTypeString=[defaults objectForKey:@"DefaultIncidentTypeString"];
    DefaultsIncidentNameString=[defaults objectForKey:@"DefaultsIncidentNameString"];
    SegmentStringCheck=[defaults objectForKey:@"SegmentStringCheck"];
    CheckIncidentString=[defaults objectForKey:@"CheckIncidentString"];

    if([DefaultEventTypeString isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        lblreportregion.text = DefaultRegionIDString;
        lblreportbranch.text = DefaultBranchIDString;
        lblreportsite.text = DefaultSiteIDString;
        //  lblreportinjurytype.text=DefaultIncidentTypeString;
        txtreportlocation.text = DefaultLocationString;
        txtreportdate.text = DefaultDateString;
        txtreporttime.text = DefaultTimeString;
        txtreportemp.text = DefaultEmployeeNameString;
        txtreportregion.text=DefaultRegionNameString;
        txtreportbranch.text=DefaultBranchNameString;
        txtreportsite.text=DefaultSiteNameString;
        //  txtreportinjurytype.text = DefaultsIncidentNameString;

    }
    else if ([DefaultEventTypeString isEqualToString:@"2"])
    {
        lblnearregion.text = DefaultRegionIDString;
        lblnearbranch.text = DefaultBranchIDString;
        lblnearsite.text = DefaultSiteIDString;
        txtnearlocation.text = DefaultLocationString;
        txtneardate.text = DefaultDateString;
        txtneartime.text = DefaultTimeString;
        txtnearemp.text = DefaultEmployeeNameString;
        txtnearregion.text=DefaultRegionNameString;
        txtnearbranch.text=DefaultBranchNameString;
        txtnearsite.text=DefaultSiteNameString;
    }
    else if ([DefaultEventTypeString isEqualToString:@"3"])
    {
        lblspotingregion.text = DefaultRegionIDString;
        lblspotingbranch.text = DefaultBranchIDString;
        lblspotingsite.text = DefaultSiteIDString;
        txtspotinglocation.text = DefaultLocationString;
        txtspotingdate.text = DefaultDateString;
        txtspotingtime.text = DefaultTimeString;
        txtsportingemp.text = DefaultEmployeeNameString;
        txtspotingregion.text=DefaultRegionNameString;
        txtspotingbranch.text=DefaultBranchNameString;
        txtspotingsite.text=DefaultSiteNameString;
    }

    if([SegmentStringCheck isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
        viewspoting.hidden=NO;
        viewnear.hidden=YES;
        viewreport.hidden=YES;
    }
    else if ([SegmentStringCheck isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
        viewspoting.hidden=YES;
        viewnear.hidden=NO;
        viewreport.hidden=YES;
        //Near...

        [self nearserverconnection];
        [self nearserverconnectionincident];
        [self nearserverconnectionactivity];
    }
    else if ([SegmentStringCheck isEqualToString:@"2"])
    {
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 2;
        viewspoting.hidden=YES;
        viewnear.hidden=YES;
        viewreport.hidden=NO;


        //Report...

        [self reportserverconnection];
        [self reportserverconnectioninjury];
    }
    else
    {
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
        viewspoting.hidden=NO;
        viewnear.hidden=YES;
        viewreport.hidden=YES;
    }


    //.........................//
    //Sporting Hide Code...

    //Table...
    tablesportingbranch.hidden=YES;
    tablesportingregion.hidden=YES;
    tablesportingsite.hidden=YES;

    //Label...
    lblsportingactivitytype.hidden=YES;
    lblsportingdept.hidden=YES;
    lblsportingemp.hidden=YES;
    lblspotingbranch.hidden=YES;
    lblspotingincidenttype.hidden=YES;
    lblspotingregion.hidden=YES;
    lblspotingsite.hidden=YES;



    //TextFieldDelegate...
    txtspotingsite.delegate=self;
    txtsportingemp.delegate=self;
    txtspotinglocation.delegate=self;

    //Date Picker...
    pickerspotingdate.hidden=YES;
    pickerspotingtime.hidden=YES;


    //............................//

    //Near Hide Code...

    //View...
   // viewnear.hidden=YES;

    //Table...
    tablenearbranch.hidden=YES;
    tablenearregion.hidden=YES;
    tablenearsite.hidden=YES;

    //Label...
    lblnearactivitytype.hidden=YES;
    lblnearbranch.hidden=YES;
    lblneardept.hidden=YES;
    lblnearemp.hidden=YES;
    lblnearincidenttype.hidden=YES;
    lblnearregion.hidden=YES;
    lblnearsite.hidden=YES;



    //TextFieldDelegate..
    txtnearsite.delegate=self;
    txtnearemp.delegate=self;
    txtnearlocation.delegate=self;

    //Date Picker...
    pickerneardate.hidden=YES;
    pickerneartime.hidden=YES;

    //...........................//

    //Report Hide View Code...

    //View...
   // viewreport.hidden=YES;

    //Table...
    tablereportbranch.hidden=YES;
    tablereportinjurytype.hidden=YES;
    tablereportregion.hidden=YES;
    tablereportsite.hidden=YES;

    //Label...
    lblreportbranch.hidden=YES;
    lblreportdept.hidden=YES;
    lblreportemp.hidden=YES;
    lblreportinjurytype.hidden=YES;
    lblreportregion.hidden=YES;
    lblreportsite.hidden=YES;

    //TextFieldDelegate...
    txtreportsite.delegate=self;
    txtreportemp.delegate=self;
    txtreportlocation.delegate=self;

    //Date Picker...
    pickerreporttime.hidden=YES;
    pickereportdate.hidden=YES;

    //.............................//

    //Font Asowme

    //Show...
    lblspotingShow.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:15];
    lblspotingShow.textColor =  [UIColor blackColor];
    lblspotingShow.text =  [NSString awesomeIcon:FaEye];

    //Scroll View...
    [scrollspoting setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 500)];
    [scrollnear setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 500)];
    [scrollreport setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 730)];


    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandler:)];
    [gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    //Button Diamiter...

    //Spoting Button...

    btnsportinghideadd.layer.cornerRadius = 4; // this value vary as per your desire
    btnsportinghideadd.clipsToBounds = YES;

    //Near Button...

    btnnearhideadd.layer.cornerRadius = 4; // this value vary as per your desire
    btnnearhideadd.clipsToBounds = YES;

    //Report Button...

    btnreportnext.layer.cornerRadius = 4; // this value vary as per your desire
    btnreportnext.clipsToBounds = YES;

    //Spoting...

    [self spotingserverconnection];
    [self spotingserverconnectionactivity];
    [self spotingserverconnectionincident];


     [txtspotingsite addTarget:self action:@selector(spotingtextFieldDidChangeSite:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];


    // prevents the scroll view from swallowing up the touch event of child buttons

    [txtnearsite addTarget:self action:@selector(neartextFieldDidChangeSite:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

    [txtreportsite addTarget:self action:@selector(reporttextFieldDidChangeSite:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesturereportinjury = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideSubViewreportinjury)];

    // prevents the scroll view from swallowing up the touch event of child buttons
    tapGesturereportinjury.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    [scrollreport addGestureRecognizer:tapGesturereportinjury];

    IssueSelectedIDarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    IssueSelectedNamearray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    ReportInjurySelectedNamearray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ReportInjurySelectedIDarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    [self testInternetConnection];


    //Spoting Date and Time..


    NSDateFormatter *Spotingdateformatter;

    Spotingdateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [Spotingdateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    SpotingdateString = [Spotingdateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"Current Time =%@",SpotingdateString);
    CurrentDate=SpotingdateString;


    NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *Spotingtimeformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [Spotingtimeformatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
    SpotingTimeString = [Spotingtimeformatter stringFromDate:now];
    NSLog(@"newDateString %@", SpotingTimeString);

    //Near Date and Time..


    NSDateFormatter *Neardateformatter;

    Neardateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [Neardateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NeardateString = [Neardateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"Current Time =%@",NeardateString);


    NSDate * nowNear = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *Neartimeformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [Neartimeformatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
    NearTimeString = [Neartimeformatter stringFromDate:nowNear];
    NSLog(@"newDateString %@", NearTimeString);


    //Report Date and Time..


    NSDateFormatter *Reportdateformatter;

    Reportdateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [Reportdateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    ReportdateString = [Reportdateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"Current Time =%@",ReportdateString);


    NSDate * nowReport = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *Reporttimeformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [Reporttimeformatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
    ReportTimeString = [Reporttimeformatter stringFromDate:nowReport];
    NSLog(@"newDateString %@", ReportTimeString);

}
```

Its working to much slow. Is there is any way to speed it up?

```
ViewName *Incedent =[[ViewName alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewName" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:Incedent animated:YES];
```

I have used this code to pushviewcontroller.

Comment: You have lots of code redundancy, so optimize your code work first.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy How to do that ??

Comment: Avoid naming your var with an uppercase. Why do you use 3 different `NSDateFormatter` for the same stuff? If you use the same piece of code in each ViewController, you may want to sublass them, or at least add protocol/extension.

Comment: I would say you should first start to create custom classes of your views to get objects for each view, also refactor the duplicate code and finaly call your object init in viewDidLoad so you get a much cleaner viewController and also keep the overview of your views/classes/project

Comment: also as @Larme mentioned, `NSDateFormatter` are heavy on usage. So better create one and change the `setDateFormat` for the single Formatter

Comment: @Muju You should always call your function from viewdidload if required but never write all that code in viewdidload . Make your methods specifying what your code is for and call from viewdidload.

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate what your code is doing, and find out *where* it is slow. I don't know what this method is doing, but I'm betting the line:

```
[self testInternetConnection];
```

is one of the problems. Comment out that line, and see what happens.

Comment: Well, yes... but what happening in 'checking internet connection'? Is it trying for 10 seconds to make a connection? Is it testing if 10 different servers can be reached? Do you *have* to check connection at that point in your code?